# sortable new order error get value tkEmail

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-sortable

I need to sort items that are within div with the same id and class. I have problems to return the value of tkEmail tag. I can not get the value.
example:
item 1
Order: 0 Value: 1

HTML:

```
<div id="sortable">
  <div class='sortear' tkEmail='1'>Item 1</div>
  <div class='sortear' tkEmail='2'>Item 2</div>
</div>

<br>

<div id="sortable">
  <div class='sortear' tkEmail='3'>Item 3</div>
  <div class='sortear' tkEmail='4'>Item 4</div>
</div>
```

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('div#sortable').sortable({
        update: function () { novaOrdem() },
    });
});

function novaOrdem(){
  $('div#sortable').each(function (i) {
    alert($(this).attr('tkEmail'))
  });
    }
```

Comment: http://api.jqueryui.com/sortable/

Comment: `Id`s have to be unique. You can't have two `divs` with an `id` of `sortable`

Answer (score 0):

`Id`s have to be unique and you're not actually checking the child `divs` in the call to `each`. `$('div#sortable').children()` will get you what you want. Also, `tkEmail` is not valid and it would be better practice to use a `data` attribute e.g. `data-tk-email`:

**HTML:**

```
<div id="sortable">
  <div class='sortear' data-tk-email='1'>Item 1</div>
  <div class='sortear' data-tk-email='2'>Item 2</div>
  <div class='sortear' data-tk-email='3'>Item 3</div>
  <div class='sortear' data-tk-email='4'>Item 4</div>
</div>
```

**JQuery:**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('div#sortable').sortable({
    update: function() {
      novaOrdem()
    },
  });
});

function novaOrdem() {
  var items = $('div#sortable').children();
  $.each(items, function() {
    alert($(this).html() + ', Order: ' + $(this).index() + ', Value: ' + $(this).data('tkEmail'))
  });
}
```

**[Fiddle Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/yassarikhan786/bh4t68d9/)**